# How to find the top scores of an objective?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am trying to figure out how to find the top scores for a Kills objective. I have the Kills at the criteria playerKillCount, but that doesn't really matter.

I wanted it so I can effectively take the top 3 scores of the objective, and put them on signs, as you I can use selectors in signs along with blockdata.

I have tried my method, which is to remove all the scores until they reach 0, and see which player had a minimum of one, however it seems a little inefficient. Any way this can be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## command

`scoreboard players set highest scb -2147483648
execute (entities that needs to compare the score) ~ ~ ~ scoreboard players operation highest scb > @e[c=1] scb`

## Principle:

`highest = INT_MIN
for i in entities:
  if i.scb > highest:
    highest = i.scb`

Comment: Yes! This principle helped me create a mechanism that would lead to the solution! I just had to figure out how to detect scores were equal after seeing this principle, however I guess that was not necessary.